# Wordpress: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_option()

Tags: php, wordpress

I've searched almost everywhere, but proposed answers didn't help me.

Problem: I've got a Wordpress installation, last version (3.6.1). I've done a clean install multiple times, looked into the `wp-includes/option.php` and other files and I'm pretty sure it all works and all has the correct content.

I'm developing a plugin, and I'm making use of the Wordpress-defined function `get_option`. Whenever my code calls that function, I get a `500: internal server error` response. Weird, cause the code of a plugin should be called from within the Wordpress framework...

Make it even more weird: other functions defined in those included files, like `add_options_page`, work perfectly and behave like they should.

So, for example, this works:

```
$pageTitle = "Title for my Options Page";
$menuLink = "Title for my Menu Link";
$userAccessLevel = 8; //that's admin
$pageSlug = "slug-to-my-plugin-options-page";
$callbackFunction = array($this, 'optionsPage');
add_options_page($pageTitle, $menuLink, $userAccessLevel, 
        $pageSlug, $callbackFunction);
```

But this doesn't:

```
get_option("ntp_myoption");
```

Both `add_options_page` and `get_option` are defined in source files in the same folder (`wp-includes\option.php` and `wp-includes\plugin.php`), both functions are effectively in those files, both blocks of code above are in the same file in my plugin, I didn't include or require any file.

Anyone has a clue?

---

As asked, the full block of code from where I call `get_option` - it is from the constructor of my class that wraps the plugin.

```
function __construct() {
    global $wpdb;
    $this->table_iso = $wpdb->prefix . "ntp_iso";
    $this->pluginUrl = get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin';
}
```

Also maybe worth to mention: I've got a class that wraps the actual plugin, and in the bottom of that .php file, I've got (outside the class definition), this code:

```
global $tp;
$tp = new MyPlugin();
$plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($tp, 'install'));
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array($tp, 'deactivate'));
add_action('add_meta_boxes', array($tp, 'init'));
if (is_admin()) {
    add_action('admin_menu', array($tp, 'addOptionsPage'));
    add_filter("plugin_action_links_$plugin", array($tp, 'addSettingsLink'));
}
```

These all work like a charm.

Comment: Try re-uploading all files and folders - except the `wp-content` folder - from a fresh download of [latest WordPress](http://wordpress.org/latest.zip).

Comment: look at the server's error log to see if there's any details about the 500.

Comment: @AmalMurali I already tried that three times. The content in all those files are exactly the same on the server as they are in a fresh download.

Comment: @MarcB the error log just says `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_option() in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/my-plugin.php on line 30`

Comment: Please post the exact block of code from where you're calling get_option ?

Comment: @testuser See my answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect wp-includes\option.php is not being loaded.

Just for grins, right before the call to get_options() add

`include_once('wp-includes\option.php');`

Or try calling something else in option.php like: `update_option(null);`

`option.php` is included from inside `wp-includes/functions.php` while `plugin.php` gets included in one of several different places.

You can see all the files that are currently included/required by inserting this into your code:

```
 $includedStuff = get_included_files();
 print_r($includedStuff);
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Well... Improving. Apparently I'm not in the Wordpress framework in my plugin. So I added that include, now the error is `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apply_filters() in /var/www/wp-includes/option.php on line 40`

Comment: (I added `include_once('/var/www/wp-includes/option.php');` as he didn't find `wp-includes/option.php` on it's own, which seems logical enough)

Comment: You might want to just add `wp-includes/functions.php` that included option.php.   Also, you need plugin.php as well as option.php

Comment: @testuser Actually ./wp-settings.php should take care of both plugins.php and functions.php.  Include the ./wp-settings.php file

Comment: so when I check for the included_files right above my `register_activation_hook` code, it prints a bunch of included files including `wp-settings.php`. When I check for those included files in my constructor, it also prints the same results. When I check for these files from another function, I get only my own PHP file as a result.

Comment: But, but, but, adding the include to wp-settings.php did solve the problem. You're a hero! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I got the same Fatal Error and then I loaded the wp-config.php file with relevant path.

My file was **wp-content/plugins/myplugin/css/mystyle.php**

I added following code at the top of the page. Then **get_option()** function worked perfectly.

```
require_once('../../../../wp-config.php');
```

May be this would be help.

Regards

Comment: I tried something like that, but then I just got different errors about files required by wp-config.php that were not found. I re-installed Wordpress to fix the problem, I guess some files were corrupted. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: Did you try to include wp-config.php and wp-load.php files like above?

Comment: I'm not sure which files I included, but I'm pretty sure I tried wp-config and I think also wp-load.php, but it didn't work... Anyway, I figured it was my code that wasn't working as I did a fresh re-install of Wordpress and refactored my plugin completely and now everything works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can test to see if options.php is working:

http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/options.php

If your options have been saved then they will be listed.

But...

add_options_page is for the dashboard menu.

What you need is add_option in order to use get_option

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option

Comment: All those functions are working fine, except for get_option. I've got a function that uses add_option too and that doesn't crash (works as a charm). And it does happen before I do the get_option-call as I see it appear in the database... In any case I shouldn't get a 500 when I try to retrieve a non-existent option from my Wordpress database, and certainly not a "call to undefined function".

Comment: Have you tried adding get_option directly following the add_option and echo the string? Or you could always try a fresh install of WP on a sub-domain with the 2013 theme. This pretty much takes things back to basics. You then install your plugin and see what happens. If exactly the same then the problem is the plugin not WP.  Sorry for the waffly answer but going back to basics is often the best way to track down issues.

Comment: Have you got a customised htaccess? That can throw up errors. But it looks more and more like a DB issue. A fresh install on a sub domain will help narrow down the problem. It's possible that your development has corrupted the DB which is why you get the error. Also try  the clean options plugin to again reset everything.

Comment: I already thought it wouldn't be WP, as I re-uploaded the wp-admin and wp-includes from a fresh download multiple times... but now I'm even more convinced, as I tried everything you said - fresh install, fresh DB, on a subdomain, WP2013 theme, still my plugin gave the same error. It's gotta be something in my code that is not working :/

Comment: Also tried `get_option` right after the `add_option`, and THAT WORKS. So it has to be linked with the moment/ position where the other function is called from that things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I used Sumith's Code but edited it a little - It was the only code that worked amongst the codes mentioned here.

Here's mine:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../../wp-config.php');
```

Comment: A forward slash must be added after the `dirname()`. Also the number of `../` depends on the current plugin directory structure, so it is not always four `../`.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add a note here for anyone getting the "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function apply_filter" error. I did a google search for this error and found this question.

**NOTE:** You may need to check your function spelling, to make sure you have "apply_filters", plural, not "apply_filter" singular, as this was my problem (which lead me to this post!).