# fatal error get_option() when trying to enqueue a css file with php variables

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to enqueue a css file (`override.php`) file from my plugin that includes php (sample code below)

```
$fineprint_font_size=get_option('fineprint_font_size');
        if($fineprint_font_size){
            echo '<style type="text/css">   .fineprint {font-size:'.$fineprint_font_size.';}</style>';
        }
```

When pull up my WP site I get the following error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function: get_option()`. How can I load this file into wp_head like you would with a normal `wp_enueue_style`?

Thanks again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326761/wordpress-php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-get-option

Comment: Thanks, but i am not following. I may need a little more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this above that code:

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '\wp-includes\functions.php');
```

That will load all necessary files so that get_option() will work.

Comment: Thanks, i have tried that and i get the following error:

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include_once(wp-includes\functions.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/content/21/6435121/html/arborscaper/wp-content/plugins/clipit-coupons/lib/inc/css/clipit-overrides.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />

Comment: Thanks Manishie, but that did not seem to work:

<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function get_home_path() in <b>/home/content/21/6435121/html/arborscaper/wp-content/plugins/clipit-coupons/lib/inc/css/clipit-overrides.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />

Comment: Didn't work. ..