# error message "www/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 69" since last wordpress update 5.5.3

Tags: php, wordpress, localization, ovh, divi

Since the last update of wordpress 5.5.3, i've a 505 error. from the debug mode, i've this error.

configuration:

- wordpress 5.5.3
- divi theme
- OVH server provider
- PHP 7.2

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_option()
> in /home/website/www/wp-includes/l10n.php:69 Stack trace: #0
> /home/website/www/wp-includes/l10n.php(137): get_locale() #1
> /home/website/www/wp-includes/l10n.php(828): determine_locale() #2
> /home/website/www/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(41):
> load_default_textdomain() #3 [internal function]:
> WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #4 {main} thrown in
> /home/lecatamakp/www/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 69

some solutions, i did but don't work.

- restore a backup from 5 days.
- disable `plugins` folder
- disable `theme` folder
- raise the the php_memory limit to 256MB
- change the PHP version
- compare an old backup (15days) with the actual app with `diff -rq backup actual_app`  and i have not difference. there are absolutely the same.

the problem come from `l10n.php`

```
unction get_locale() {
global $locale, $wp_local_package;

if ( isset( $locale ) ) {
    /**
     * Filters the locale ID of the WordPress installation.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     *
     * @param string $locale The locale ID.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'locale', $locale );
}

if ( isset( $wp_local_package ) ) {
    $locale = $wp_local_package;
}

// WPLANG was defined in wp-config.
if ( defined( 'WPLANG' ) ) {
    $locale = WPLANG;
}

// If multisite, check options.
if ( is_multisite() ) {
    // Don't check blog option when installing.
    if ( wp_installing() ) {
        $ms_locale = get_site_option( 'WPLANG' );
    } else {
        $ms_locale = get_option( 'WPLANG' );
        if ( false === $ms_locale ) {
            $ms_locale = get_site_option( 'WPLANG' );
        }
    }

    if ( false !== $ms_locale ) {
        $locale = $ms_locale;
    }
} else {
    $db_locale = get_option( 'WPLANG' ); #--------------HERE IS THE PROBLEM----------------
    if ( false !== $db_locale ) {
        $locale = $db_locale;
    }
}

if ( empty( $locale ) ) {
    $locale = 'en_US';
}

/** This filter is documented in wp-includes/l10n.php */
return apply_filters( 'locale', $locale );
```

}

some user had a problem with this file `l10n.php`

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/l10n-php137-crashes-entrie-website/

i've change for a fresh file but don't work.

I will try to install wordpress 5.5.1

Somebody have a workaround technic ? Many thanks

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326761/wordpress-php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-get-option) help?

Comment: Thanks for your reactive reply. I didn't try it cause the downgrading of wordpress did the job.

Answer (score 1):

the downgrade to wordpress version 5.5.1 did the job wery well.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on the apache http2 module is enabled.

curl  -I --http2 -s <yoursite.rootDomain> | grep HTTP

if it's not enabled please take a look at this (in case the OVH stack is LAMP) :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-with-http-2-support-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: thanks, the response of the server to your command line is: HTTP/2 200    so it seems enabled